# Oracle XML Forest

Tags: xml, oracle

I have created a XML using XML forest, the problem I am facing is that it doesn't create the empty tags when the values are null. Is there a way out for this issue?

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use xmlelement is you want to represent a NULL with a blank tab.

eg

```
SQL> select xmlelement("test", xmlagg(xmlelement("foo", a)))
  2  from (select 'a' a from dual union all select null from dual);

XMLELEMENT("TEST",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("FOO",A)))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<test><foo>a</foo><foo></foo></test>
```

vs

```
SQL> select xmlelement("test", xmlagg(xmlforest(a as "foo")))
  2  from (select 'a' a from dual union all select null from dual);

XMLELEMENT("TEST",XMLAGG(XMLFOREST(AAS"FOO")))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<test><foo>a</foo></test>
```